# Print Preview Infinitely Growing Page Count

Tags: 2010

We are experiencing a SP2010 print preview problem where the page count infinitely grows. The expected response from a SharePoint page when selecting page preview is to show the current page content. While the current page is displayed inside the preview window, however, the page counter "Page 1 to xyz" continues to grow to numbers like 340 or 560, etc. I am not familiar with this issue, nor do I understand what the counter is actually counting (site pages, farm pages). Do you have any ideas? I have posted a screenshot of the print preview of this common list. The astronomical page growth count is highlighted in a red circle. Our print.css code is posted below this image.

Here is a screenshot on my SkyDrive cloud account:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=fe71d14157c605df&resid=FE71D14157C605DF!194&parid=FE71D14157C605DF!156

Here is the print.css stylesheet:

```
@media print{

.ms-globallinks,.ms-siteaction,.ms-areaseparatorcorner,.ms-titlearealeft,.ms-searchform,.ms-banner,.ms-buttonheightwidth,
.ms-areaseparatorright,.ms-titlearearight,.ms-rightareacell,.ms-leftareacell,.ms-areaseparatorleft{
display:none;
}

/* Insert your print stylsheet here */
#s4-titlerow, #s4-statusbarcontainer, #s4-topheader2 { display:none; visibility: hidden; }

#s4-leftpanel { display:none; visibility: hidden; }
#MSO_ContentTable { margin: 0 0 0 0 }

.s4-notdlg { display: none; }

/* convert font to printer friendly points */
body {
    background: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#s4-workspace,
#s4-bodyContainer {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 5%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    float: none !important;
    color: black;
    background: transparent none;
}

}
```

Comment: I would like to note that I do not believe the CSS StyleSheet has any impact on whether the error exists or not. The erroneous behavior of the print preview was happening before and after the addition of the print.css stylesheet.

Comment: Kit, I know this response is late, however, I didn't want to not recognize your helpful assistance. Although I no longer have access to the source code for this question I will keep your code suggestions on-hand for future use. At the moment I cannot test your edited code, but I will try re-creating a mock site and see how your code modified the output. I will post back when I have an answer. Thank you for your help.